# Where in JBoss EAP 7.3 domain management console can I view the JMS queue message counts?

Tags: jms, jboss-eap-7

I have JBoss EAP 7.3 in domain mode with 3 host controllers each with a single server. I have set up a JMS server via the GUI management console with some queues and I am trying to test it now. The Java code writes to the JMS queue without any exception. The listener is supposed to print a message, and I don't see it so I assume I set something up incorrectly. Now I'm trying to just confirm there is a message added to the queue.

[This documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/messaging_statistics) says I should be able to see the number of messages sent to the queue:

> To view messaging statistics from the management console, navigate to the Messaging - ActiveMQ subsystem from the Runtime tab and click View. Select the messaging provider and click View.

However when I go to the runtime tab of the domain controller I don't see anything top level menu with "Messaging - ActiveMQ". I can go to the individual hosts and click on JMS but there is just some static text about JMS and no option to view the message counts.

Where in JBoss EAP 7.3 domain management console can I view the JMS message counts?

Edit:
I should mention that I set up my 'cluster' to test jboss. Its actually 3 host controllers and one domain controller all running on the same machine (when we go to production we will have multiple machines and 1 host controller per machine). For now Im just testing though. I spin up 1 server per host controller each running on different ports (using port offset property). I'm wondering if activemq is using some port or there is some other resource conflict since I have 3 servers all running on the same host. I believe jboss runs these activemq servers embedded within the application itself without spinning up a new process.  I have not found any good documentation about the architecture of jboss messaging in EAP 7.3 (where the process runs, what ports it uses, etc). Its not clear if jboss creates one activemq instance for each of my 3 servers or if jboss just picks a host and starts the server there.

Comment: Did you enable the statistics ?

Comment: their documentation mentions you dont need statistics enabled to see counts. That is for more detailed statistics like performance etc. But yes I have it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the server group and all the servers. I think different configuration profiles might work differently. I cant remember what I used when I originally created the profile for the server. When I recreated the profile I cloned "full-ha" I used "full-ha-sockets" when I created the server group. Maybe I used something else originally. Now I can see the individual queues and counts if I click runtime-> servergroup -> servername -> messaging.

It's still not clear why the messaging module was there under the server before but not showing the queues.

Comment: and .... I spoke too soon. The option was there and now its gone. no idea what Im doing that breaks it. I guess I repeat the steps till I figure out where it is breaking and post back later.

Comment: this is starting to piss me off. I was able to get to the counts last night before I went to bed. Now its disappeared again ... seems like some bug in jboss maybe?

Comment: idk. after wasting like 3 days I installed jboss eap 7.2 and I can see the jms subsystems without issue so far. Seems like a bug in jboss. Thanks for wasting the last few days of my life red hat.